# How to refactor sql query in a foreach

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

This is my code that works:

```
foreach (var r in rlist)
    {
        if (r.IndexOf("_") != -1)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(r.Split('_')[1]);
            var x_tmp = (from x in db.tblX where x.x_id == my_id && x.x_id == id select x).First();
            x_tmp.order = someNumber;
        }
     }
     db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to refactor this?

Comment: Belongs here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var x_tmp in db.tblX.Where(x => rlist.Where(r => r.indexOf("_") != -1).Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Split('_')[1])).Contains(x.x_id)))
     x_tmp = someNumber;
db.SaveChanges();
```

What for a "my_id" ?